# Select the first duplicated element

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hql

I have 2 Classes in JAVA ( ***MODEL1*** && ***MODEL2*** ) 
As you can see here :

```
MODEL1_ID   ACTN_DTE   MODEL2_ID    
---------- --------- --------------
         1 14/11/19  18         
      1000 14/11/19  4
      1001 14/11/19  19
      1002 14/11/19  4
      1003 14/11/19  4
      1004 14/11/19  18
      2000 14/11/19  5
```

I am trying to find a way with SQL Or HQL to get all elements from MODEL1 that have a list of MODEL2_ID , **get only the first (min MODEL1_ID) MODEL1 per MODEL2_ID *( in case if it's duplucated )***.

Exemple :
Input : MODEL2_ID in (18,4,19,5)

```
MODEL1_ID   ACTN_DTE   MODEL2_ID    
---------- --------- --------------
         1 14/11/19  18         
      1000 14/11/19  4
      1001 14/11/19  19
      2000 14/11/19  5
```

Comment: Are you asking just for a SQL query? Because you talk JAVA but you show SQL, and that is confusing...

Comment: Yes I am asking for SQL query , I put java to explain more in case of someone want to put an HQL query

Comment: Have your tried sql aggregate functions?

Comment: SQL queries act on tables not Java classes. What is the sample data you posted? Is it a table?

Comment: What do you mean by first result? Is the order important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select MIN(MODEL1_ID) FROM table GROUP BY (MODEL2_ID)`

Comment: This yields the last not the first element and it assumes that the ids correspond with creation time/are always ordered like that.

Comment: Well, he could use MIN instead. He just asked for a singular MODEL1_ID that has MODEL2_ID.

Comment: He asked for the first result in the bold text.

Comment: He should explain to us what he mean with "*the first*"

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that by "first" you mean the minimum `actn_date` and the question just has a useless sample of data (because all the values are the same).

If so, you can use aggregation with `keep` to get the first value *by `actn_date`*:

```
select model2_id, min(actn_date) as actn_date,
       min(model1_id) keep (dense_rank first order by actn_date) as model1_id
from t
group by model2_id;
```